# UITextInput: reset multi stage input suggestions

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextinput

In my app I have implemented `UITextInput` to handle multi stage text input for my custom `UITextField`. I was wondering if anyone knows how to reset the multi stage input suggestions that appear above the keyboard when typing on the Japanese keyboard:

[image]

I'm just wanting to clear out the marked text and reset everything. The only way to do this right now is if the user manually presses the return key or dismisses the `UITextView`.

Is there any way to do this in the code? In looking at the documentation for `UITextInput`, it's not obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by doing the following:

```
[self.inputDelegate selectionWillChange:self];
self.selectedTextRange = NSMakeRange(self.cursor.position, 0);
self.markedTextRange = NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0);
[self.inputDelegate selectionDidChange:self];
```